# getting 100% accuracy on yolov4 darknet?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, face-recognition, face-detection, yolov4

why i'am achieving 100% accuracy? what's could be the possible reason for getting this much accuracy? iam training my model on thermal images for 4 classes.
classes are lablled as 1)rosy
2)daisy
3)tony
4)shine
each class has 60 images. total images given for training 240 images.
Note: i didnt used any augmentation techniques

1. i kept iterations 2000, therefore steps = 1600,1800 (i didnt used 8000 becuase i wanted to reduce the training time)
2. batches= 32, subdivisions=8, network size = 416*416
3. the weights saved during training are giving good results while testing on thermal images, its detecting the faces with 96% accuracy
   [training char](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNTri.png)

```
Loading weights from /mydrive/yolov4_thermal/train_weights/yolov4_custom_best.weights...
seen 64, trained: 35 K-images (0 Kilo-batches_64) 
Done! Loaded 162 layers from weights-file 

calculation mAP (mean average precision)...
Detection layer: 139 - type = 28 
Detection layer: 150 - type = 28 
Detection layer: 161 - type = 28 
24
detections_count = 44, unique_truth_count = 24  
class_id = 0, name = rose, ap = 100.00%      (TP = 8, FP = 0) 
class_id = 1, name = daisy, ap = 100.00%     (TP = 7, FP = 0) 
class_id = 2, name = tony, ap = 100.00%      (TP = 5, FP = 0) 
class_id = 3, name = shine, ap = 100.00%     (TP = 4, FP = 0) 

for conf_thresh = 0.25, precision = 1.00, recall = 1.00, F1-score = 1.00 
for conf_thresh = 0.25, TP = 24, FP = 0, FN = 0, average IoU = 81.05 % 

IoU threshold = 50 %, used Area-Under-Curve for each unique Recall 
mean average precision (mAP@0.50) = 1.000000, or 100.00 % 
Total Detection Time: 1 Seconds
```

Comment: What is the problem? You have no FP and achieve 100%, why you unhappy?

Comment: how come accuracy is going directly to 100% from 62% ? how is this possible ?

Comment: plzz check the training chart

Comment: it is normal, model overfitting your training data.